# Evaluating results of a JMeter diagram

Tags: testing, jmeter

I made a jmeter test against a site and for the loading frequency I copyed some example ddata to my thread group from a tutorial.

I get a straight green line as graph result. Under thati can read that throuhput is 123 /minute.

I do not get any other lines. What does it mean? Could it open the site?

I specyfield the path for the thread group but I didn't write anything to the path of httprequest. Can that be the problem? Or my computer is too slow?

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. 
I suggest using the View Results in Tree for debugging.

You can also check out some video tutorials on using JMeter here:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series